# Tomcat SPring Autowired ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a Spring project with this Structure
Maven Parent Project
|
-----> Spring MVC Project (A)
|
-----> Spring JPA Project (B)

I have a @Controller in A that @Autowire an Interface in (B).

The project compiles fine, but when I run the project in Tomcat I have this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.et.dto.core.dao.ParametroDao
```

Inside my war file I have both projects, project A compile as a WAR file and project B inside the war in /WEB-INF/lib.

If I copy  jar from project B into Tomcat/lib, the problem solves but I don't like to do this every time I compile. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have to copy the jar each time? Once is enought, isn't it?

Comment: Your MVC Project should just import the configuration from your JPA project

Comment: @bigdestroyer, every time that i change the B project i ned to copy.

Comment: @Hank I will try to do this tomorrow. Thanks.